# Google Apps Script: Setting color of an event using Calendar API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I would like to set specific colors for events.

I believe I have to use the Calendar API. I cannot figure out how to do this.

The code I am trying is:

```
var event = CalendarApp.getOwnedCalendarById(calendarID).createEvent(class, startTime, endTime, {description:lessonPlanDataComplete[t], colorId: 11});
```

The `colorId` 11 should set as *red*, but all events coming out as default color.

Any helps/hints gratefully received,

Many thanks, Simon

Comment: Have you tried using `setColor` instead? It takes a hexadecimal color string. In none of the `createEvent` methods do I see color as an optional parameter.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Ihave tried using setColor but can't get that to work either. Does anyone have some example code I could copy. Many thanks, Simon

Answer (score 7):

It is actually possible using the advanced Calendar Service.

([This post was helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35482104/changing-color-on-event-in-google-calendar))

The code to create a new event goes like this : (inspired by [Google's example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar))

```
function createEvent() {
  var calendarId = 'primary';
  var event = {
    summary: 'Other test',
    location: 'right here',
    description:' chat... ;-)',
    start: {
      dateTime: new Date().toISOString()
    },
    end: {
      dateTime: new Date(new Date().getTime()+3600000).toISOString()
    },
    attendees: [
      {email: 'user@gmail.com'}
    ],
    // Red background. Use Calendar.Colors.get() for the full list.
    colorId: 11
  };
  event = Calendar.Events.insert(event, calendarId);
  Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());
}
```

and to modify an existing event (having its ID) goes like that :

```
function ChangeEventColor(){
  var calendarId = 'primary';
  var eventId = 'omv°°°°°°°°°°8jbs'
  var event = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eventId)
  Logger.log('current color = '+event.colorId)
  event.colorId = 11
  Calendar.Events.patch(event,calendarId,eventId);
  Logger.log('new color = '+event.colorId)
}
```

Color codes are listed using (for example) the [Google online API tryout here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/colors/get)

The advanced Google Calendar Service has to be enabled before you run this code using the ressources menu in the script editor, see illustration below.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is always possible. Try it out instead.

in your function:

```
var newEvent = calendar.createEvent(event_title, event_start_time, event_end_time, 
  {
    location: event_location, 
    guests: newGuests, 
    sendInvites: 'true', 
    description: event_description
  }
);

newEvent.setColor('4');
```

Refer to: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-color

The string to set is the numerical string representation of event color.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible. You can use setColor on a Calendar but not on an event. You can send feedback about the API from the developer pages about this and hope that it gets added.

Meanwhile, I suggest that you create a calendar with the desired colour and place all events in there as this will make them have that colour.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm not creating, but updating existing calendar events, but I think stood be similar.

```
event.colorId = filterColorId;
Calendar.Events.patch(event, 'primary', event.id)
```

The whole solution can be found here
http://isbyr.com/colour-code-google-calendar-events-automatically-using-google-apps-script/