# Google Sheets to Calendar Apps Script ColorId

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

This is my introduction to Google's script editor, I have very little knowledge on the matter. Anyway, I am trying to run a script to create events on Google Calendar with data from Google Sheets. I ended up with the code below.

```
function createCalendarEvent() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('ID');

  var startRow = 2;  
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();   
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows-1, numColumns);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  var complete = "Done";

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var client = row[0]; //Client
    var task = row[1];  //Task
    var employee = row[2] //Employee
    var date = new Date(row[3]);  //Start Date
    var rDate = new Date(row[4]); //End Date
    var addguest = row[8]; //Employee Email
    var employeecolor = row[9]; //Employee Calendar Color
    var eventID = row[10]; //Scheduled?

    Logger.log(row)

    if (eventID != complete) {
      var currentCell = sheet.getRange(startRow + i, numColumns);
      calendar.createAllDayEvent(employee+ " - " + client, rDate, 
      {description: task, colorId: employeecolor, guests: addguest, sendInvites: true

      });

      currentCell.setValue(complete);

    }
  }
}
```

The script creates an event and sends guests email invites but the only thing I can't get to work is the ColorID. Right now, the colorID cell in Sheets generates a number between 1-11. I've tried hex color codes and Enum EventColor properties from Google's reference but nothing seems to change the color from the default calendar color. Help. Not sure what's wrong and I am sorry if this has been answered already. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using Advanced Services, you cannot set the event color. You can see this on the description of the `setColor` method on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#setcolorcolor).
To change the color of an event, insert it into the calendar with the correct color.
The object you are passing as options does not have those properties, check [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#advanced-parameters) for available properties.

However, if you are using Advanced Services you can set the colors as explained on [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35492002/11869748)

Comment: calendar advanced service allows to set color of a single event, see doc here : https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events , full answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548227/google-apps-script-setting-color-of-an-event-using-calendar-api/35492002#35492002

Comment: Thank you @Sergeinsas for the information! Great Answer!